# How to set cookies in a rails 3 app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cookies

I've added this to my `application.js` but it doesn't create a cookie. In fact it breaks all the other javascript functions below it.

```
function getTimeZone() {
    var current_time = new Date();
    var offset = -(current_time.getTimezoneOffset() / 60);
    Cookie.set({timezone: offset});
}
getTimeZone();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cookie` isn't a build in JavaScript class and I don't think it's part of Prototype or jQuery either. So unless you've included some JavaScript that defines `Cookie`, then I'd say that's your problem.

Cookie's are a bit of a pain to work with in raw JavaScript so I'd recommend using one of the two plugins below to make life easier.

For Prototype:
http://jason.pureconcepts.net/articles/javascript_cookie_object

For jQuery:
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/